# TelegramBotAPI как переслать видео?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Столкнулся недавно с такой проблемой, каким образом можно переслать видео в телеграм боте.
Фотографию можно переслать следующим образом:

`bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, message.photo[-1].file_id, caption=text, reply_markup=imk)`

Есть ли аналогичный способ переслать видео в телеграм боте и получить id видео?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете использовать [sendVideo](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendvideo) метод, в документации всё подробно описано. Чтобы получить видео из сообщения, обращайтесь к объекту `Video`. Для pytelegrambotapi это будет выглядеть так:

```py
bot.send_video(message.chat.id, message.video.file_id, caption=text, reply_markup=imk)
```

Comment: спасибо большое